# csvreader with tabular (to generate entire table) with caption

Tags: csvsimple

I have the following MWE that works:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
    Project, Size
    A_b,-0.1237466
    b,0.04632737
    \end{filecontents*}

    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{csvsimple}

    \begin{document}

    \csvreader[tabular=l|r,
    respect underscore=true,
    table head=\hline Project & Size \\\hline\hline,
    late after line=\\\hline]%
    {\jobname.csv}{}%
    {\csvcoli & \csvcolii}%

\end{document}
```

However, I'm unable to put a `\caption` on the table. I have tried

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
    Project, Size
    A_b,-0.1237466
    b,0.04632737
    \end{filecontents*}

    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{csvsimple}

    \begin{document}

    \csvreader[tabular=l|r,
    respect underscore=true,
    table head=\caption{Sample table} 
    \hline Project & Size \\\hline\hline,
    late after line=\\\hline]%
    {\jobname.csv}{}%
    {\csvcoli & \csvcolii}%

\end{document}
```

but I get all kinds of errors I can't debug easily. Where does one put a `\caption{}` for a table generated this way?

Note: I don't want to use `csvreader` inside a `\begin{table}...` because the `respect underscore=true` doesn't seem to work properly when I do that, and I have underscores in my data.

Comment: Can you please add a complete copyable document instead of code snippets?

Comment: @MisoSoup OK - done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but `respect underscore=true` works perfectly within `\begin{table} ... \end{table}`.

However, there is also a solution using `longtable`, here them both:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
  Project, Size
  A_b,-0.1237466
  b,0.04632737
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\listoftables

\begin{table}[htb]\centering
\caption{Sample table}\label{tab:test}
\csvreader[%
  tabular=l|r,
  respect underscore=true,
  table head=\hline Project & Size \\\hline\hline,
  late after line=\\\hline
]%
{\jobname.csv}{}%
{\csvcoli & \csvcolii}%
\end{table}

As you can see in table~\ref{tab:test}, \texttt{respect underscore=true} works perfectly within \texttt{\textbackslash begin\{table\}\dots\textbackslash end\{table\}} 

\csvreader[
    longtable=l|r,
    respect underscore=true,
    table head=\caption{Sample table with \texttt{longtable}}\label{tab:test2}\\\hline Project & Size \\\hline\hline\endhead
        \hline\endfoot,
    late after line=\\
]{\jobname.csv}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was used to using longtable with no environment, but should have realized tabular only does the tabular part. This is the best solution in my case.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator Thank you for accepting my answer!

Answer (score 1):

For example can you use environment `center` and add inside it `\captionof` (needs to load package `caption`). You need an environment to be able to use `\captionof` and in your case you can use environment `center` to get the table centered ...

See the following code

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
  Project, Size
  A_b,-0.1237466
  b,0.04632737
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{caption} % <================================= for \captionof


\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{center} % <======================================================
\captionof{table}{Test}\label{tab:test} % <=============================
\csvreader[%
  tabular=l|r,
  respect underscore=true,
  table head=\hline Project & Size \\\hline\hline,
  late after line=\\\hline
]%
{\jobname.csv}{}%
{\csvcoli & \csvcolii}%
\end{center} % <========================================================

As you can see in table~\ref{tab:test} \dots

\end{document}
```

and its result if you compile it with `pdflatex`:

[image: resulting pdf]

As you can see, the `_` is not displayed correct in the table.  Now add the line

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <======================== needed for pdflatex
```

to the preamble and you get well printed `_` in the table. You need `[T1]{fontenc}` for correct printed document with `pdflatex`.  Then you also get the `_` printed with environment `table`.

Please see the following code

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
  Project, Size
  A_b,-0.1237466
  b,0.04632737
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <======================== needed for pdflatex
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{caption} % <================================= for \captionof


\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{center} % <======================================================
\captionof{table}{Test}\label{tab:test} % <=============================
\csvreader[%
  tabular=l|r,
  respect underscore=true,
  table head=\hline Project & Size \\\hline\hline,
  late after line=\\\hline
]%
{\jobname.csv}{}%
{\csvcoli & \csvcolii}%
\end{center} % <========================================================

As you can see in table~\ref{tab:test} \dots

\begin{table}[hb] % <===================================================
\caption{Test1}\label{tab:test1} % <====================================
\centering % <==========================================================
\csvreader[%
  tabular=l|r,
  respect underscore=true,
  table head=\hline Project & Size \\\hline\hline,
  late after line=\\\hline
]%
{\jobname.csv}{}%
{\csvcoli & \csvcolii}%
\end{table} % <========================================================

As you can see in table~\ref{tab:test1} \dots

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: result with fontenc and pdflatex]

If you compile with `lualatex` or `xelatex` you do not need to call package `fontenc`. So comment the line `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in the mwe above and compile with `lualatex` then you get the similar result:

[image: result with lualatex]

Answer (score 0):

workaround with `\captionof` from the `caption` package:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
Project, Size
A_b,-0.1237466
b,0.04632737
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\captionof{table}{caption text}
\csvreader[tabular=l|r,
respect underscore=true,
table head=\hline Project & Size \\\hline\hline,
late after line=\\\hline]%
{\jobname.csv}{}%
{\csvcoli & \csvcolii}%
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why the minipage? Won't that affect floats?